# Can I add flags to bundletool command in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-app-bundle, bundletool

Does Android Studio use `bundletool build-apks`  command while Deploying "APK from app bundle" (building app bundles)?

If so, how can I configure or add flags to that command in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Android Studio calls bundletool under the hood but you can't customize the flags passed.